# create a front end post page template withTinyMCE,

Tags: tinymce

there are alot of front end posting suggestion with wp insert post but is it posible to create a front end post submision with TinyMCE, and similiar editor

Answer (score 1):

If plugin is okay with you than you can try WP Quick Post Widget. It has Editor you are looking for and also supporting all Custom Meta Boxes. So you can use that too for front end.

Check this.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-post-widget/

Answer (score 0):

**If you got the rest of the form all set and ready you should check out nicedit.com.**   That Editor would allow you to turn your textarea into a fully functional editor.

i have to this solution while build a wordpress based article website and found that using the TinyMCE is either impossible or i havent found the right explenation..

Anyway... NiceEdit would provide a toolbar similer to wordpress one and the data will be sent along with it (if your form is build in the correct way) when submitting a post.

Hope this helps :)

p.s:
if anyone know of a way to integrate wordpress TinyMCE i would also love to know